# Can I use the Facebook logo in my app to link to a "post to Facebook' portion?

Tags: facebook, twitter, social-networking

While I understand that this is not directly linked to coding, I have an app that is ready for the app store, coded in swift. I have a 'post high score to Facebook' button, and was wondering if I am allowed to use their logo as a button. The same applies for use of the twitter logo.
Thank you :)

Answer (score -1):

I believe, you are trying to use the  ["f" logo](https://www.facebookbrand.com/) , and  [this](https://www.facebookbrand.com/guidelines?asset=2&media=1,2,3)  says, it is okay if it refers to,

> Your presence on Facebook, such as your Page, timeline, group, app or event

where `your` can be represented to the apps page or the user's page itself. That is you are allowed to do that.

I hope i am clear enough.

Comment: When you answer questions, you have to elaborate and explain minimum things. You have to include some relevant part of the answer, because links may disappear. so this is not a good answer.